# Sigma algebra generated by the sets $[n,n+1] ,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ on the real line.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The sigma algebra would need to contain complements $[n,n+1]^c = (\infty, n) \cup (n+1, \infty) $, which can be made from countable union of open sets $(n,n+1), n\in \mathbb{Z}$. It also contains singletons $[n-1,n] \cap [n, n+1] = \{n\} $.

My question is: how do I make sure that's all there is to it (or is there more). I'm having trouble since the only way I know how to find out generated sigma algebra's is to 'guess' it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are still missing some: $(n-1,n]$ can be created as the complement of the union of $(-\infty,n-1]$ and $(n,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Idontgetit I mentioned singletons ${n}$, so $(n-1,n] = (n-1,n) \cup \{n\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider sets of the form $\bigcup_{n \in I} (n,n+1) \cup E$ where $I$ and $E$ are subsets of $\mathbb  Z$. This class is clearly closed under countable unions. The complement of $\bigcup_{n \in I} (n,n+1) \cup E$ is $\bigcup_{n \notin I} (n,n+1) \cup (\mathbb Z \setminus E)$. It follows that this class is  a sigma algebra. We can now easily see that it is the smallest sigma algebra containing the intervals $[n, n+1], n 
\in \mathbb Z$.

PS: The motivation for this comes from the fact that the sigma algebra generated by a  countable partition $(E_n)$ is the class of all possible unions of the sets $E_n$.